# How to open .msg files in iframe in IE 11 browser using ActiveX Control for real native view

Tags: internet-explorer, outlook, activex

I was trying opening office documents in an iframe in IE browser using activeX control , so as to get the real native desktop application view inside browser.

I was trying something like this:

For all office documents like .doc,.docx, .pptx, .xlsx, etc. It will open the particular document inside IE 11 browser in real native view using activeX Control.

But the same when I try for .msg files ( outlook files) it does not open .msg file in outlook inside iframe.

It prompts to download the file.

Can some please help? its urget?

Comment: Are you trying to open the files using `ActiveXObject` in JavaScript or just using an add-on to open them? Please provide [a minimal code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can reproduce the issue. It can help us have a better understanding of the issue and we can also have a test. We can't find and debug the issue without any code. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Just serve different file types on a local server and give url like below in html.
 <iframe src="http://127.0.0.1:5500/test-data/getClassify.docx" height="600" width="800" id="myFrame"></iframe>

open in IE 11 and enable activeX control in settings

Comment: I tried it and both `.msg` and `.docx` files will promote a "open or save" dialog and you can choose open to open them in native desktop application. I think it's the default behavior of IE. For your issue, do you mean that it only have "save" option but no "open" option for `.msg` file?